# how do you make sure an async service call is made

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I use an async service, but I am not interested in the result.

How can I make sure that the request is sent to the service?
The service which I start asyncronous does not begin doing anything.
I believe thisis because the request is not sent..

```
 ConvertToCubeService.ConvertToCubeFaces param = new ConvertToCubeService.ConvertToCubeFaces();

        var apPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;


        param.EquirectangularFilePath=apPath+context.GetValue(this.EquirectangularImagePath);
        param.imageName = context.GetValue(this.ImageName);
        param.SaveCubicFacesDirectory = apPath + context.GetValue(this.SaveImageDirectoryPath);
        client.ConvertToCubeFacesCompleted += new EventHandler<ConvertToCubeService.ConvertToCubeFacesCompletedEventArgs>(client_ConvertToCubeFacesCompleted);
        client.ConvertToCubeFacesAsync(param);//call async the server to do the work
```

the callback does not do anything. I just added it hoping this could make it work:

```
 void client_ConvertToCubeFacesCompleted(object sender, ConvertToCubeService.ConvertToCubeFacesCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you (for testing):

Hit the service with Fiddler or WcfTestClient.exe and see the response / error? This makes sure the service is OK independent of the client code.

Modify the service so that it writes to a log when called? You can then test the client hits it ok.

PS: If you really don't care about the response from a WCF Service I believe you can set the OneWay attribute. Then you don't even have to wait for it to finish processing.